# Unable to fetch the PEM certificate

Tags: bash, shell, gitlab, sh, pem

I am trying to execute the bash command in one of the `gitlab CI/CD`  stages with the `key` and `pem` values. However, when I tried the below steps:

```
- METHOD="POST"
- key_string="${CLIENT_CERTIFICATE_KEY}"
- pem_string="${CLIENT_CERTIFICATE_PEM}"
- bash ./integration_test.sh DBT_Provision "$METHOD" "$(cat ./provision_and_unprovision_payload_dbt.json)" https://some-url/v1/provision <(printf '%s' "$key_string") <(printf '%s' "$pem_string")
```

I got this error:

```
curl: (58) could not load PEM client certificate from /dev/fd/12, LibreSSL error error:09FFF06C:PEM routines:CRYPTO_internal:no start line, (no key found, wrong pass phrase, or wrong file format?)
```

Below are a few lines from the `.sh` file:

```
echo "Invoking $1 Request..."

payload=$3

response=$(curl --key "$5" --cert "$6" -k -X "$2" -d "$payload" "$4")
echo $(curl --key "$5" --cert "$6" -k -X "$2" -d "$payload" "$4")
```

What could be the issue here?

Comment: Does it work if you use hard-coded values for the command instead of varriables? Good luck.

Comment: Your script runs curl _twice_ with $5 and $6 as input both times, but a file created with `<( process substitution )` can only be read once. Try doing `echo $response` to use the result of the first execution instead of running a second one -- not to mention that repeating a POST operation may produce results on the server you don't want.